# Multipage WIA scan (docfeeder) scans 1 page and blocks scanner

Tags: c#, documents, wia

Using C# (VS2008) and WIA - scanning to TIFF format;

When I use the scanner for 1 page on the flatbed or document feeder the method executes without any problem.
When I load multiple forms into the feeder the execution halts after scanning the first page (keeping status: "scanning to pc") but does not scan the next page(s).
The method returns the stream of the first page and halts - am able to save the stream and everything; just am lost at what to do next...

What statement am I missing? What am I missing here? TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following forum post has a nice explanation on using WIA with ADF (automatic document feeder):

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=439027

Answer (score 1):

I used some of the code from there and wrote a nice little library here:
http://adfwia.codeplex.com/

**Update:** 
I've put (and manage) the project on github now: https://github.com/gideondsouza/AutoDocumentFeed_for_WIA

Comment: I'm getting the below error at line 30 in the Form1.cs file (_Scanner.BeginScan....)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80210003'