# C# WIA scanner transfer only one image

Tags: c#, wia

I'm writing a network scanner application, using WIA. My problem now is that the transfer method only scan one image. I tried to force the parameter WIA_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT = "3088"; but the result is the same it scan just one image per time. How can I manage the document feeder and the duplex parameter?

I tried this code

```
const string WIA_SCAN_COLOR_MODE = "6146";
        const string WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI = "6147";
        const string WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI = "6148";
        const string WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL = "6149";
        const string WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL = "6150";
        const string WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS = "6151";
        const string WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS = "6152";
        const string WIA_SCAN_BRIGHTNESS_PERCENTS = "6154";
        const string WIA_SCAN_CONTRAST_PERCENTS = "6155";
        const string WIA_MANUFACTURER = "3";
        const string WIA_DESCRIPTION = "4";
        const string WIA_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT = "3088";
        //const string WIA_LAMP_WARM_UP_TIME = "6161";
        //const string WIA_IPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT =
        //const string WIA_IPS_LAMP = 
        const int widthA4at300dpi = 2480;
        const int heightA4at300dpi = 3508;
        const int widthA4at600dpi = 4960;
        const int heightA4at600dpi = 7016;

public static Image scan(DeviceInfo dev, Protocol.ScannerOptions options)
        {
            ImageFile imageFile = null;
            try
            {
                // Connect to the first available scanner
                Device device = dev.Connect();
                // Select the scanner
                Item scannerItem = device.Items[1];

                if(options.adf)
                    SetWIAProperty(device.Properties, WIA_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT, 1); //1 is feeder 2 is flatbed
                AdjustScannerSettings(scannerItem, options.dpi, 0, 0, 1250, 1700, options.brightness, options.contrast, options.color_mode);

                imageFile = (ImageFile)scannerItem.Transfer(FormatID.wiaFormatBMP);
            }
            catch (COMException e)
            {
                // Convert the error code to UINT
                uint errorCode = (uint)e.ErrorCode;

                // See the error codes
                if (errorCode == 0x80210006)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The scanner is busy or isn't ready");
                    NetScanImageServer.txt_logger.write_log("The scanner is busy or isn't ready");
                    throw new Exception("The scanner is busy or isn't ready");
                }
                else if (errorCode == 0x80210064)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The scanning process has been cancelled.");
                    NetScanImageServer.txt_logger.write_log("The scanning process has been cancelled.");
                    throw new Exception("The scanning process has been cancelled.");
                }
                else if (errorCode == 0x8021000C)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is an incorrect setting on the WIA device.");
                    NetScanImageServer.txt_logger.write_log("There is an incorrect setting on the WIA device.");
                    throw new Exception("There is an incorrect setting on the WIA device.");
                }
                else if (errorCode == 0x80210005)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The device is offline. Make sure the device is powered on and connected to the PC.");
                    NetScanImageServer.txt_logger.write_log("The device is offline. Make sure the device is powered on and connected to the PC.");
                    throw new Exception("The device is offline. Make sure the device is powered on and connected to the PC.");
                }
                else if (errorCode == 0x80210001)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An unknown error has occurred with the WIA device.");
                    NetScanImageServer.txt_logger.write_log("An unknown error has occurred with the WIA device.");
                    throw new Exception("An unknown error has occurred with the WIA device.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Errore SCANNER non pronto\n" + ex.ToString());
                NetScanImageServer.txt_logger.write_log("Errore SCANNER non pronto\n" + ex.ToString());
                throw new Exception("Errore SCANNER non pronto\n" + ex.ToString());
            }

            if(imageFile!=null)
                return ToBitmap(imageFile);
            else return null;
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60371387/scaning-multiple-pages-using-wia-on-windows-7

Comment: Ok setting the pageid property to 0 scan more than one page. But the transfer method launch a FileNotFound Exception in the end.